# Circular dependency with $compile $http

Tags: angularjs, inject, growl

I am getting a circular dependency error when using the growl angular directive:

> Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: spinnerInterceptor <- $http <- $compile [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/cdep?p0=spinnerInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/cdep?p0=spinnerInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20%24compile)

```
   angular.module('bedrock').factory('spinnerInterceptor', ['$q', 'growl', '$injector', function($q, growl, $injector) {
  var count = 0;

  function setCount(count) {
    $('#spinner .count').text(count);
  }

  return {
    request: function(config) {
      /* jshint -W017 */
      if (!count++) {
        // Start a spinner here.
        $('#spinner').show();
      }
      /* jshint +W017 */
      setCount(count);

      return config || $q.when(config);
    },
    response: function(response) {
      if (!--count) {
        // Stop the spinner here...
        $('#spinner').hide();
      }
      setCount(count);

      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (!--count) {
        // ...and here.
        $('#spinner').hide();
      }
      setCount(count);
      var $compile = $compile || $injector.get('$compile');
      if(rejection.status != 401){
        growl.addErrorMessage($compile(
            '<h3>' + rejection.config.method + ' '+ rejection.config.url + '</h3>' +
            '<hr><div>' +
                (_.isObject(rejection.data) ? ('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(rejection.data, null, 2) + '</pre>') : rejection.data) +
                '</div>' + '<a ng-click="reportError($event)"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn hoverable"></i>  Report this error</a>'),
          {
            enableHtml: true
          }
        );
      }

      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
}]).factory('timeoutInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      config.timeout = 20000;
      return config;
    }
  };
}).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('spinnerInterceptor');
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timeoutInterceptor');
}]);
```

How do i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injecting `$compile` in your interceptor, inject `$injector` and get `$compile` with `$injector.get('$compile')` (not in the interceptor initilization time). You can for example have a closure variable `$compile` that you fill once in your `responseError` method.

Comment: That seemed to fix the circular dependency issue! However I am now getting an issue actually sanitizing the HTML I am trying to $compile.  I get html.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: Your last problem may deal with what returns `$compile`.